# Cluster environment with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Does SQL Server 2008 web edition support cluster environment?

Answer (score 1):

Only Standard, Enterprise and Datacenter editions support clustering:

> [SQL 2008 - Compare Edition Features](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx)